# Why is the processor % different in Activity Monitor vs Resource Monitor?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server, activity-monitor

I'm tracking a significant difference between the processor % reported in the Activity Monitor for SQL Server vs the total processor % used in the Resource Monitor.  I'm seeing about a 50% difference between the two with the Activity Monitor always being higher.

System Specs:

- SQL Server EE 2008 R2
- Windows 2008 R2
- Bare metal
- 96 cores w/no processor affinity set (4 Physical Sockets with 12 cores each w/HyperThreading enabled)
- 768 GB of memory
- Active/Passive cluster
- Direct attach storage of SSDs

What would cause such a difference?

Which one should I be looking at?

[image: CPU Comparision]

Update:

I see that resource monitor has it split between different categories however wouldn't the "CPU - Total" graph show all CPU usage on the machine?

The Task Manager Performance tab is showing the same difference between it and Activity Monitor.

[image: Activity Monitor Vs Task Manager Performance]

- Activity Monitor is on a 1 sec refresh.

Could there be an issue with Activity Monitor not seeing that each core is HyperThreaded?  Not sure how as SQL Server sees all 96 cores.

[image: SQL Server Properties]

**Update 6/28/2018**

Even after migrating to AWS and updating the OS to Server 2012 R2 the SQL Server 2008 r2 Activity Monitor is still dramatically off from what Task Manager shows.  The below screen shot is from a load test that was just performed.  There is a visible 20% difference between the two metrics.  Even when Task Manager is reporting the overall CPU just over 55% the SQL Activity Monitor is pegged at 100%.  Metrics from the AWS Cloud watch show the same results as Task Manager so I have two data metrics that correlate with a third that isn't even in the ballpark.

[image: AWS Server]

Updated System Specs:
System Specs:

- SQL Server EE 2008 R2
- Windows 2012 Datacenter R2
- i3.16xl - Dedicated Host
- 64 cores w/no processor affinity set (2 Sockets with 32 cores each)
- 488 GB of memory
- Synchronous Mirroring
- ENA Enabled w/EBS Optimization enabled

[image]

Comment: I ignore the Resource Monitor for CPU usage.

Comment: (ignore deleted comment...missed bit about 96 cores..although maybe one is missing that each core has 2 threads?)

Comment: looking at the resource monitor shot, you have 37% usage of the CPU by services. So a total of 69% usage between that and processes.  Which is the the ballpark (within 5% overall, or 8% or so of the values), allowing for differences in sampling intervals and intensities for the two applications.

Comment: Can you please share your CPU settings of SQL Server??

Answer (score 7):

Resource monitor shows CPU from Processes and Services on two different graphs. (In your example, 32% + 37%, which means a total 69% CPU).

As for SQL Activity Monitor, it shows CPU utilization for the machine on which SQL is installed. (In your example, 64%, which is not that far from Resource monitor.)

I use a query to get the CPU utilization on my server. I run a job on my server and raise an alarm if I get an average over 90% for the last 10 minutes.

Here's my query:

```
DECLARE @ts_now bigint = (SELECT cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks)FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info); 

-- Top 10 : for the last 10 minutes
SELECT TOP(10)  100 - SystemIdle as TotalCPU,
           DATEADD(ms, -1 * (@ts_now - [timestamp]), GETDATE()) AS [Event Time] 
FROM ( 
  SELECT record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS record_id, 
        record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') 
        AS [SystemIdle], 
        record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]', 
        'int') 
        AS [SQLProcessUtilization], [timestamp] 
  FROM ( 
        SELECT [timestamp], CONVERT(xml, record) AS [record] 
        FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers 
        WHERE ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR' 
        AND record LIKE '%<SystemHealth>%') AS x 
  ) AS y 
ORDER BY record_id DESC;
```

Comment: Very nice query, Danielle.  Do you know the oldest version of SQL this will work on?

Comment: Thanks! The oldest server I have access to is SQL Server 2012. I've never tried it on older servers.

Comment: I just confirmed it does not work on 2008.  Thankfully those are getting retired soon.  I have a big script called ServerStatus that I add these snippets to.  Gives me a good understanding of what the server is up to.  This code will go into the "SQL 2012 and up" section.

Comment: @datagod, it should work on 2008 but not on 2005. Did you mean 2005 instead? There's a slight change for 2005. See here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a2c14eb5-5e2e-41e2-a40b-60af991d3e8f/query-to-monitor-the-cpu-on-sql-server-2008?forum=transactsql.

Comment: The error was caused by a different piece of code that I forgot to handle properly.  My mistake.  Glad to hear this one works on 2008.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Hi @DaniellePaquette-Harvey, Thanks for the answer, I like that we can extract the same data that the Activity Monitor is displaying.  One thing however is that just the good old Task Manager Performance tab is showing the same difference.  Please see my updates to the post.

Comment: are you running all as a privileged user?  Might it be possible that task manager's (and Resource Mon's) CPU usage does not include system processes in the grand total because the account you are running TM/RM under does not have access to system services, so cannot display individual stats of those? If this is the case, it seems odd that RM gives an overall services usage though. As to the "CPU Totals" graphs not showing service usage, probably is a mislabeling bug of MS. Appears to be "total of userspace processes"

Comment: Hum @Aaron I'm not exactly sure why. As mpag said, the Task Manager might not include all system processes. Also, from what I read, there might be some difference between the Task Manager and the Resource Monitor. It seems that Microsoft also created a "Process Explorer" which also displays CPU. I haven't tried it. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: My guess is that at some point (maybe Kernel stuff?) Task Manager and Resource Monitor and SQL Server aren't showing exactly the same values. For my part, the difference between the CPU is not big enough for me to search more. I rely on what SQL Server is giving me and it does the trick for my monitoring. I monitor three production server that way and it does the job.

Comment: @DaniellePaquette-Harvey Process Explorer by MS/sysinternals is a beautiful little program (everything you need in one EXE). I used Iarsn's taskinfo until I found Process Explorer.

Comment: @DaniellePaquette-Harvey yeah I'm going off what SQL server is saying. I'm just trying to understand what the difference is and if there is room for more load on the server that would be good to know. I have a prior generation server with the same OS and SQL versions and they track one to one. What a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

a few more details added to Danielle's query

```
DECLARE @processorGHz float = (SELECT 1.0*cpu_ticks/ms_ticks/(1000000) FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info); -- divided by 1 million as that is 1 billion (GHz) divided by 1000 (ms/s)
DECLARE @ts_now bigint = (SELECT ms_ticks from sys.dm_os_sys_info); --cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks) reduces to just ms_ticks. 1/(1/x)=x
DECLARE @processors int = (SELECT cpu_count from sys.dm_os_sys_info);
DECLARE @qs datetime = GETDATE();
-- Top 60 : for the last hour
SELECT TOP(60)
    DATEADD(ms, -1 * (@ts_now - [timestamp]), @qs) AS [Snapshot Time],
    100 - SystemIdle as [Total CPU Burden (%)],
    COALESCE(CAST(
        NULLIF(CONVERT(decimal(18, 4), 100.0 * UMT / (@processorGHz * 1000000 * 60 * @processors)),0.0)
    as varchar(10)),'') as [SQL Server Userspace CPU Usage (%)],
    COALESCE(CAST(
        NULLIF(CONVERT(decimal(18, 4), 100.0 * KMT / (@processorGHz * 1000000 * 60 * @processors)),0.0)
    as varchar(10)),'') as [SQL Server Kernel CPU Usage (%)],
    COALESCE(CAST(
        NULLIF(
            CONVERT(decimal(18, 4), 
                100.0 * UMT / (@processorGHz * 1000000 * 60 * @processors) +
                100.0 * KMT / (@processorGHz * 1000000 * 60 * @processors)),0.0)
    as varchar(10)),'') as [Total CPU Usage by SQL Server (%)],
    SPU as [SQL Processor Usage (% trunc)],
    Mem as [Total System Physical Memory Used (%)]
FROM ( 
    SELECT
        record.value('(./Record/@id)[1]', 'int') AS record_id, 
        record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)[1]', 'int') AS [SystemIdle], 
        record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)[1]','int') AS [SPU],
        record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/UserModeTime)[1]','int') AS UMT,
        record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/KernelModeTime)[1]','int') AS KMT,
        record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/MemoryUtilization)[1]','int') AS Mem,
        [timestamp]
    FROM ( 
        SELECT
            [timestamp],
            CONVERT(xml, record) AS [record] 
        FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers 
        WHERE 
            ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR' AND
            (record LIKE '%<SystemHealth>%')
    ) AS x 
) AS y 
ORDER BY record_id DESC;
```

I'd appreciate any feedback on if the `SQL Server Userspace CPU Usage %`-type columns are accurate. I use very little of my CPU resources for long enough to capture in the dataset on my server. Unfortunately the documentation for UserModeTime and KernelModeTime of sys.dm_os_ring_buffers is completely lacking at MSDN, so I'm not sure if it's measuring clock time, processor time, processor cycles or what. These numbers don't seem to be measuring all processes on the computer, as I'll often get 0s, but the processors are definitely being used, so I surmise they reflect CPU usage by SQL server.